# How to include \deprecated text but have no deprecated list page

Tags: doxygen

\deprecated text seems only to be included in the documentation if GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST = YES.

Is it possible to include this text, but *not* to have a deprecated list page (in the HTMLHelp CHM)?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of doxygen you are using?  Also, I'd be interested in knowing *why* you don't want the reference list.  Is the  desire not to have the list stronger or weaker than using the keyword *deprecated*?  I'm just thinking one hack would be to use `@attention "This is Deprecated"` as @attention does not generate a list page.

Comment: We'd like the deprecated information to appear in the API documentation, but don't want the deprecated list entry to appear at the top level of the CHM Contents list. As I haven't yet figured a way to move it elsewhere (it's not in `doxygen_layout.xml`),  it's preferable not to see it at all.

`@attention` may be possible, but `@deprecated` tags are already used in the source code, so we'd prefer not to change this.

Thanks!

Comment: Getting the Contents structure sensible is a common pain - spent the last few days doing something similar (with the sidebar on HTML).  I don't know if it's possible to get these lists off the top-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply overrule the @deprecated command via an alias. I.e. define:

```
ALIASES = deprecated=@attention
```

in the configuration file and @deprecated will be parsed as if @attention was written.

Comment: Thanks; adapted this to `ALIASES = "deprecated=@par Deprecated\n"`